# DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE can not be resolved or is not a filed

Tags: android, device-admin

I got a problem with this code.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO){
    DevicePolicyManager mDPM;
    mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager)context_.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
    mDPM.wipeData(0);
}
```

the errors are: `FROYO can not be resolved or is not a filed` in line 1

and `DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE can not be resolved or is not a filed` in line 3

I've got a problems with my Librarys before, they wont find by eclipse.

For some tests i import my hole projects to another PC and there it works. Our Admin told me to create a new local user in Windows and also imoprt it there with a new Workspace, it also works.

I swiched my PC-User the a new one and Import all my projects, but now i got this error for one of them.

I also find this in Problems:

```
The method removeActiveAdmin(ComponentName) is undefined for the type DevicePolicyManager
```

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'am able  to fix it, it looks like that my eclipse lost the connection to the ADT plugin. It cant use functions for API 8 or higher.

After the reinstall from the plugins for eclipse it works again

Answer (score 0):

I am posting it for the people that might explore this in the future. I found that my problem went away after I changed Android target in the `project.properties` file:

```
target=android-19
```

`19` is the current (latest) Android version available. This error happens even in Android website's examples.